# Design SQL Insert When Using Modular Address

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design

In designing my database, I created the addresses as a modular system. One table has the `AddressID`, and the rest of the address tables have a row for both the `AddressID` and their type of information, (i.e. Phone Number, Email Address, Physical Address, etc.). This is to save space and add extensibility for addresses that might not have information for every column and future addresses that might have more information than I anticipate.

Other entities in the database have a column for `AddressID`, (tables like `InsuranceCompany` and `BranchOffice`, etc.). When I'm inserting a new row in one of these entities, I need to supply the `AddressID`. I'm wondering, what is the best way of designing this? Can I have a view with all of the various information types, (Phone Number, Physical Address, etc.) as columns and then do an insert into the view first, and take an output of the `AddressID` for an insert into the `InsuranceOffice` entity? Should I use a stored procedure?

```
Table 1 - Address

   AddressID              int identity

Table 2 - PhoneNumber

   AddressID              int
   PhoneNumber            varchar(10)

Table 3 - PhoneNumberForeignPart

   AddressID              int
   CountryCode            varchar(5)
   PhoneNumberSuffix      varchar(5)

Table 4 - PhoneNumberExtenstion

   AddressID              int
   PhoneNumberExtension   varchar(5)

Table 5 - EmailAddress

   AddressID              int
   EmailAddress           varchar(50)

...

Table 10 - InsuranceCompany

   InsuranceCompanyID     int identity
   InsuranceCompanyName   varchar(40)
   AddressID              int
   Disabled               bit
```

Thanks.

Comment: To be completely honest with you, I don't think the realization of how headache-inducing maintaining this structure will be has set in. If you want an address table, put all of the columns in it related to a physical address (street, city, state, country, phone, etc.). Then, use the foreign key like you are in `InsuranceCompany`. It's ok to have `null` fields when `null` means something (e.g. having Street1, Street2, and Street3 in one table is fine; Street2 and Street3 are almost always going to be null -- you wouldn't put those in a different table, would you?).

Comment: Furthers to Cory's excellent point. A database should be designed using 3rd Normal Form(http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/third-normal-form.htm). It will be a lot easier to maintain. Adding a new column would not be an issue because you can set a default or allow `NULL` when adding a column.

Comment: I agree 10000% with @Cᴏʀʏ. I would add a couple things though. You have 10 characters for a phone number but you indicate that you need to be able to support international data. That isn't enough room. You also have email address as 50. You need to make that a LOT bigger for some email addresses. The real max length is absolutely ridiculous but you probably want at least 100 characters. If you do stick with this crazy design you probably also want to include a unique index on almost every table with a foreign key. You can't allow things like a single address having multiple CountryCodes.

Answer (score 1):

Alright you bums, telling me that my idea is a foolish one.

Clearly, you are right.  Thank you @Cory, and @Eric S, and @Sean Lange.

I combined the disparate tables into one 'Address' table.  I tried a combination of Stored Procedures, User Functions, and Views before giving up, but it became obvious that I was just trying to fit a square peg into a round hole.

Following your advice @Sean Lange, I expanded the length of the email field.  Thank you.